# Extend texture to different objects

Tags: texturing, uv, objects

Is there a way to extend a texture to different objects? My problem is that i have two objects and i want to scale one (in three.js) and change the position of the other. One object is upon the other and with the textures being differents the view is ruined. I must use UV Mapping.
Here is an image
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just asking how to UV map the image and use it on two different objects?

Comment: I want the same image to extend on two different objects. For example i want one texture on the object with the handle plus the object under it

Comment: ok, so you want to texture multiple objects but have them all use the same image.

Comment: Yes thats right!

Comment: Why do you not use the same material for both objects?

Comment: @parameciostudio I did this but the result is the same with the picture above

Comment: @IraklisBekiaris maybe this tutorial can help you: http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/learning-unwrapping-uvw-maps.php, expecially the screenshot at the bottom of the page

Comment: Yes thank you bro! I think this is what i was looking for, i will try to make it happen and i will send feedback

Comment: nice tutorial but he manipulates one object, i need to manipulate 2 o more

Comment: @parameciostudio You were right, i had to make one material for both objects then unwrap and then project from view. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Select the object to unwrap, and while in *edit mode* press  <kbd>U</kbd>  to unwrap. Then, select the image you want to UV map to your objects from the list of available images (if more than one has been added to your scene), while in the UV/ image editor. Repeat for your other objects. In the attached gif, I just used a stack of cubes for simplicity, but the method should work in any case.
[image]

Comment: I do not know if i understand right what you are doing but this does not extend one texture to different objects. What i want is one texture to wrap the surfaces of my objects like it is one object!

Comment: *I am really new in blender :)